# GWT celltable How to create selectioncell in edittextcell?

Tags: java, gwt, cell, gwt-2.2-celltable

I want to create editable cell with datatype boolean.

I don't want to use selectioncell for boolean data type

My testBooleanColumn column's cell contains string with value true,false..........

when I will click on cell present in testBooleanColumn then that cell should be editable and In that editable cell  I want to show selection cell with value(true,false).
when user changes value from selectioncell either true or false that value set to editable cell in testBooleanColumn

How to do this? any hint ? or sample code for this use case ?

Comment: Your question is a really hard to understand. Maybe you can clarify. You have a cellTable with a bunch of Columns. One column (testBooleanColumn) should be editable but you don't want to use a SelectionCell?
I assume what you want to achieve is to display the SelectionCell when you click into the cell and display some other cell in read mode (when the cell has no focus). is that correct?

Comment: @timeu Thanks for reply you are correct.I want to display the SelectionCell when user click into the editableTextCell and display some other cell(editableTextCell) in read mode (when the cell has no focus).

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to do that:

1. Use a **CompositeCell** with an **ClickTextCell** and a **SelectionCell** and override the render method of the CompositeCell to render only the ClickTextCell.
   When the ClickTextCell is clicked it will automatically call the **ValueUpdater**.
   In the update function of the ValueUpdater you have to set some boolean value in your ClickTextCell. Then you have to check in the render method of your CompositeCell this boolean value and if it is set, then render the SelectionCell instead of the ClickTextCell.
2. Create a custom cell extending AbstractEditableCell for example (see this [tutorial](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells.html)) and implement the functionality yourself. You can check out the code for [SelectionCell](http://www.google.com/codesearch#A1edwVHBClQ/user/src/com/google/gwt/cell/client/SelectionCell.java&q=SelectionCell%20package%3ahttp://google-web-toolkit%5C.googlecode%5C.com) and [EditTextCell](http://www.google.com/codesearch#A1edwVHBClQ/user/src/com/google/gwt/cell/client/EditTextCell.java) and copy most of it. Basically you have to have some kind of a flag which is set when the cell gets focus. In the render method you have to either display a dropdownlist or just a text.
3. Extend either EditTextCell or SelectionCell and implement the missing functionality. The advantage is that you can probably re-use some of the render methods and you don't have to write the complete render code yourself.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Have you created such CustomeCell? any Sample code for the same?

Comment: I haven't really created one but you can just look at the code for SelectionCell or EditTextCell. It should be the same.